Sound ocassionally working on laptop
So I have an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installation on a drive which I use on both my desktop computer and my laptop as boot drive. There's no problem on the desktop, but when using the installation on the laptop the sound will normally not work (showing 'Dummy Output' as the only device). Sometimes, without doing anything in particular, I boot up the laptop and sound does work correctly.

I don't think it's a problem with the laptop itself because it used to have its own installation of Ubuntu (the same version) some time ago and it'd always work fine. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!
